# using removeClass("hidden") to show/hide a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating an interactive game using HTML, CSS and jQuery. On the bottom right hand corner there is a question mark (an image file, not text). What I am trying to make happen is when the question mark is clicked on and held down , a box shows up with help on it. When the mouse is released the box dissapears. There are three different help boxes for 3 different pages.

## help is the question mark image

.help-box refers to all the boxes from different pages
.growing-plants & .label-flower & .types-animal are the different help boxes.
This is my code :

script.js file:

```
$('#help').mousedown(function() {
  if (currentSection == 1) {
    $('.growing-plants').removeClass("hidden");
  } else if (currentSection == 2) {
    $('.label-flower').removeClass("hidden");
  } else if (currentSection == 3) {
    $('.types-animal').removeClass("hidden");
  }
});

$('#help').mouseup(function() {
  if (currentSection == 1) {
      $('.growing-plants').addClass("hidden");
  } else if (currentSection == 2) {
      $('.label-flower').addClass("hidden");
  } else if (currentSection == 3) {
      $('.types-animal').addClass("hidden");
  }
```

});

style.css file:

```
#help {
     position: absolute;
     left:900px;
}

.help-box {
     position: absolute;
     top: 200px;
     left: 220px;
     z-index: 15;
}

.growing-plants {
     overflow: hidden;
}

.label-flower {
     overflow: hidden;
}

.types-animal {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

html file:

```
<img src="images/help-growing-plants.png" class="help-box growing-plants" alt="help" width="600" height="400">
<img src="images/help-label-flower.png" class="help-box label-flower" alt="help" width="600" height="400">
<img src="images/help-types-animal.png" class="help-box label-flower" alt="help" width="600" height="400">
```

Any help or suggestions would be so appreciated!!!!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Yea, what is the problem..?

Comment: adding and removing such class has no effect since it's not defined. try doing css('overflow', 'visible') or css('overflow', 'hidden') instead.

Comment: Not even sure JS is needed for this. Wouldn't just `:active` work?

Comment: the question is how do i make it work because this does not work

Comment: where is current section being set?

Comment: So how you are you defining the `.hidden` class...you can;t apply something that doesn't exist.

Comment: What if there is no mouse?

Comment: I dont know my teacher has helped me with some if it and now I'm really stuck. What do i need to define to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initially hide your elements by styling them with `display: none;`

```
.help-box {
     position: absolute;
     top: 200px;
     left: 220px;
     z-index: 15;
     display: none;
}
```

Then you can use jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()`

```
$('#help').mousedown(function() {
  if (currentSection == 1) {
    $('.growing-plants').show();
  } else if (currentSection == 2) {
    $('.label-flower').show();
  } else if (currentSection == 3) {
    $('.types-animal').show();
  }
});

$('#help').mouseup(function() {
  if (currentSection == 1) {
      $('.growing-plants').hide();
  } else if (currentSection == 2) {
      $('.label-flower').hide();
  } else if (currentSection == 3) {
      $('.types-animal').hide();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your  "hidden" class is defined in a part of the code that you are not linking the problem is that using the `.addClass(classNameYouWantToAdd)` or `.removeClass(classNameYouWantToAdd)` is looking for a "hidden" class that you haven't defined.

The rest of your code should work if you defined a class that you then apply to the div containing what you want to hide like this

```
.hidden {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```